# Add FreezeCoreOrbitals on ElectronicStructureProblem

Tags: programming, qiskit, chemistry

I want to freeze core orbitals of my molecule and I know ElectronicStructureProblem has the possibility (es_problem = ElectronicStructureProblem(driver=driver, q_molecule_transformers=FreezeCoreTransformer())). Then, when I run the code to calculate the ground state energy of my molecule (res = calc.solve(problem=es_problem)), it says that 'FreezeCoreTransformer' object is not iterable. Which is the way then to freeze core orbitals without using deprecated libraries of Qiskit?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature/issues/163 for info:

Summary

The ElectronicStructureProblem takes a driver and list of transformers, so you would do it like this

```
problem = ElectronicStructureProblem(driver, transformers=[FreezeCoreTransformer()])
```